# How to test a function with a Subscription that returns void

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, rxjs

I have a TypeScript `ModelService` with an `edit` function:

```
edit(model: Model): Observable<Model> {
  const body = JSON.stringify(model);
  return this.http.put(`/models/edit/${model.id}`, body));
}
```

And I have a TypeScript `EditComponent` with an `edit` function that subscribes to the service and navigates when it gets the response:

```
edit(model: Model): void {
  this.service
    .edit(model)
    .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate([`/models/details/${model.id}`]);
}
```

What is the best way to test this component's `edit` function?

I have a Jasmine test that does this:

```
// Setup
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [EditComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ModelService,
      useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('ModelService', ['edit'])
    }
  ]
});
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditComponent);
const component = fixture.componentInstance;
const modelService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ModelService);
fixture.detectChanges();

// Test
it('should call edit', () => {
  fakeAsync(() => {
    component.edit(model);
    expect(modelService.edit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

But with this test, I always get `SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS` when it runs. My understanding of [`fakeAsync`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) is that it runs synchronously so I thought this would work.

I've also tried using numerous variations of `async`, `tick()`, and `done()`, but those either give the same message or fail with `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` when calling the component's `edit` function.

In other tests, I've been able to use `return fixture.whenStable().then()` and that works fine (as described [here](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async)), but I don't think it works here since the component function is returning `void` instead of a Promise.

What is a better way to test this component function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For `SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS`**

That doesn't seem like the right way to use `fakeAsync` and that is why it said no expectations. It should be:

```
it('should call edit', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.edit(model);
  expect(modelService.edit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Anyway, the `modelService.edit()` is actually a call that can be expected synchronously, because it is called inside `component.edit()`.

So you can simply test it like this:

```
it('should call edit', () => {
  component.edit(model);
  expect(modelService.edit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

---

**For `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`**

Because you create spy object without any returns. Hence, `modalService.edit()` return `undefined` and cannot be read property 'subscribe'. In this case, I normally stub its result by creating new Observable or using [of()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of) and return values that this component may need to interact with.

```
jasmine.createSpyObj('ModelService', { edit: of() })
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly and makes perfect sense sense.If I add a new provider to the `TestBed` like `{ provide: Router, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', { navigate: of([`/models/details/${model.id}`]) }) },`, do you know if there is a way to add an `expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();` (or something similar) to the test?

Comment: You're welcome! Just assign the spy obj created by Jasmine to a variable then you can `expect` them later. Something like this `let router = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', { navigate: of([/models/details/${model.id}]) })` then `expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled()`. Basically, `expect()` requires spied function which can be made from `spyOn` to that function of an object or made an obj with spied functions (what `createSpyObj()` does) then pass in the spied function. [Here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#routing-component) is an official guide to handle testing a routing component.